# Philosophical idea for repetition of doing things leads to loss of interest in subject?

Tags: repetition

I am searching for a term that refers to doing something will eventually result in boredom from that something.

Comment: There's the proverb **familiarity breeds contempt**.

Comment: Monotony? 
: a lack of change that makes something boring .

Comment: The term *fatigue* often follows a noun describing the formerly enjoyed treat or pasttime - *caviar fatigue*.

Comment: Consider "Jadedness", the state of being "blasé".

Answer (score 1):

I like to cite **The Law of Diminishing Marginal Returns**. The added investment of time, yields less enjoyment for each hour put into that activity. But since it does not reference interest/boredom specifically, this is perhaps a bit broader of a term than you want.

http://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/lawofdiminishingmarginalreturn.asp

Comment: Though mathematically identical, the [Law of Decreasing Marginal Utility](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/lawofdiminishingutility.asp) is more germane to the specific concept